# Unable to set the value in the localStorage after decoding using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

My objective is to store the decoded value into the localStorage. Here is the link i got after decoding the JWT token `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: "ABC"`. How to set the value in localStorage. **I want to store the value of this link as `ABC` in localStorage, not the full link**

I tried like `localStorage.setItem("name", ? )`. I couldn't able to figure it out what should i right in place of **?**.

I want only the link value - ABC, Can anyone help me in getting this value?

Answer (score 0):

Your link is a string or an object? Because if it's an object like this:-

`obj {
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name: ABC
}`

then you can store it this way:-

`localStorage.setItem(name, objName[http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name])`

but if it's a string then you need to split that value from the string.